# Why Filter is structural while Interpreter is behavioral?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, filter, interpreter, object-oriented-analysis

Both **Filter** and **Interpreter** Design Patterns look like much similar task oriented. Filter does filtering a list for some criteria, while Interpreter is doing pretty much same for a single element.

But I wonder why **Filter** is **Structural** and **Interpreter** is **behavioral**. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is true that they are "task-oriented", these two patterns actually refer to different purposes, let's take the example of an SQLTable class.

**Filter pattern** can serve to filter/remove/hide, more generally affect the structure of your database but don't modify its behavior at all.

*Example 1* : Once filtered, it's only a new SQLTable with less/more rows and maybe less/more columns

**Interpreter pattern** belongs to behavioral pattern, in the sense that it modifes the behavior of an object (often represented with the help of a structural pattern such as Composite). The difference lies in the interpretation of the structure to behave differently.

*Example 2*: Once interpreted as a csv-table, your SQLTable can now be exported to a PDF file

I guess your misunderstanding comes from the fact that they are both **applied to a structure in order to create something else** but the actual difference lies in their **intent** rather than their concrete implementation which are relatively close in practice

Comment: [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/whats-the-difference-between-a-bridge-a-mediator-and-a-wrapper/2290#2290) has an excellent answer regarding patterns that differ by intent rather than implementation.